# The blood flow or flowS to the lungs?

Tags: grammar

What of the two following options is the right?

> 1. The blood flow to the lungs
> 2. The blood flowS to the lungs

I'm asking my question because I thought that the blood is equals to the water somehow.

Thank you!

Comment: The first is a phrase, while the second one is a whole sentence. Both *are* grammatical.

Comment: Depends on what you want to say...

Comment: Please add more details about what you are trying to say (not as a comment, but as an edit to the question). _After we applied the tourniquet, the blood flow stopped._ That's grammatically correct, but so is this: _If you stand up too quickly, the blood flows out of your brain, and you may feel lightheaded._ Please rephrase your question, without the faulty assumption that one option is right and the other is wrong. Maybe a better question would be: "When should I use one instead of the other?"

Comment: Nope. Your revision hasn't cleared up things, unfortunately. Just as mentioned, both *the blood flows to the lungs* and *the blood flow to the lungs* are **still** equally valid. It depends on the context and structure to determine which to use.

Comment: neither of these are great sentences. the commas don't make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the context:

> **Blood flow** is the continuous circulation of blood in the cardiovascular system

Here we use it as a *term*.

> **Blood flows** *(you may change into **"runs"**)* through arteries, veins and capillaries.

Here we have an *action*.

Comment: Your answer could use the words "noun" and " verb"...

Comment: Thank you for the short and nice explanation! Excellent! Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Neither really works the way you have it, but if we maintain the word order we can get two phrases that use “flow” differently and require different endings for that word.

> Example 1: 
>   Blood flow to the lungs was prevented by an arterial obstruction.

Here, “flow” is being used as a noun. It’s modified by “blood” which is being used as an adjective. This is similar to usages such as “water glass” or “rain spout”. This pairing is so common that “bloodflow” is often written as a single word, just like “headache” or “backfire”.

> Example 2: 
>   Blood flows to the lungs when it is not prevented by an arterial obstruction.

In example 2, “flows” is a verb. It’s a present simple mood that represents a conditional but essentially timeframe-independent state. The noun “blood” is said to flow somewhere.

> Example 3: Where blood flows, there is blood flow.